# Incorrect information in windows task manager

Tags: windows, task-manager

I was uploading some files so I decided to look at windows task manager to see what my network usage was. It seemed correct, but when I looked at the total bytes sent during uptime it said I had sent about 18.5 exabytes. What is going on? I haven't uploaded more than 4 gigabytes.

Comment: There is what is called "Protocol overhead" on file transfers, more than just the actual data is being sent, but does not explain what you are seeing.....http://sd.wareonearth.com/~phil/net/overhead/

Comment: I did the same thing yesterday, but it did not do this.  It occurred over the course of several hours, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen what may be the same bug. My NIC driver was reporting the "bytes sent" in a 64-bit integer (no problem so far). But it had the two halves of the integer swapped from what they should have been so all the number reported were about 4 billion times as large as they should have been. The only cure: either switch to a NIC whose driver didn't have that bug, or wait for a driver update that fixed it. 
This was w-a-a-y back in early XP time, so I'd be surprised to see it today, but...